# How to get a multi-attributes vector from an SRTM raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, srtm

I split an SRTM raster into 3 different raster files representing the altitude, the slope and the exposure, using QGIS DEM analysis tools.

How can I output a single vector file with the 3 attributes reunited on the same object, being a point or a 1 hectare polygon ?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Welcome and please take the tour http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour